# add auto reload function

Tags: jquery, ajax, refresh, reload

I'm trying to make a gadget with "FeedEk jQuery"
but problem is i cant add auto update feed in that code! for example i wanna change and reload feeds every 5 minutes.

**Source:** http://www.jquery-plugins.net/FeedEK/FeedEK.html

**Default Function:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function(){     
   $('#divRss').FeedEk({
   FeedUrl : 'http://www.my site.ir/rss.xml',
   MaxCount : 5,
   ShowDesc : false,
   ShowPubDate: true
  });  
});
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="divRss"></div>
```

My question is, how i can add auto update or refresh timer for every 5 mins on this jquery code?

And next question is, how i can add word limit for description, for example just 200 word in description.

Comment: Wrap the above in a function so it's re-usable, then call that method directly and place another reference in a `setinterval()` call. (Assuming that the `.FeedEk` is executing, otherwise you're going to need to look in that library and see how you can issue a refresh)

Comment: Wow! thanks but i'm very noob with these code's or jquery! could u please making this code for me? i really appreciate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to explain what I meant in the comment, take the above and wrap it in a function (we'll call it `loadFeed()`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function(){     
  function loadFeed(){ // wrapper function
    $('#divRss').FeedEk({
     FeedUrl : 'http://www.my site.ir/rss.xml',
     MaxCount : 5,
     ShowDesc : false,
     ShowPubDate: true
    }); 
  } // /wrapper
});
</script>
```

Next, just after it make a direct call to that function so it executed on page load:

```
loadFeed();
```

Then, place a recurring call (using [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval)) just below that so it updates:

```
setInterval(loadFeed, 300 * 1e3); // every 5 minutes [300 seconds]
```

So, altogether:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function(){     
  function loadFeed(){ // wrapper function
    $('#divRss').FeedEk({
     FeedUrl : 'http://www.my site.ir/rss.xml',
     MaxCount : 5,
     ShowDesc : false,
     ShowPubDate: true
    }); 
  } // /wrapper
  loadFeed();
  setInterval(loadFeed, 300 * 1e3);
});
</script>
```

Regarding your second question, you're probably going to need to open the script and modify the `entry.content` portion within the `$.ajax` call so it only shows as much information as you want. If it's minified (all one line) you can use [jsBeautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/) to make it a little easier to read and work with.

Comment: thanks but it does not work and not showing anything with your code! :( ERROR: Uncaught ReferenceError: loadfeed is not defined feed.html:26
(anonymous function) feed.html:26
l jquery.js:2
c.fireWith jquery.js:2
v.extend.ready jquery.js:2
A

Comment: Is the feed located on the same site as the script is executing from?

Comment: Oops, needs to be `loadFeed()` not `loadfeed()` (note capital F--I'll also update my answer)

Comment: WOW! Now it's working! thank u so much my friend, is there anyway to add word cut for descriptions?

Comment: @Alireza: As i mentioned in the bottom of my answer, for that you're going to need to modify what `entry.content` outputs within the `FeedEk` script. And without knowing what kind of content that holds, it's hard to write something that could word-limit.